Critique my understanding of the determinant's relation to linear independence
If $det(A) = 0$ then the columns of $A$ are linearly dependent. This is a result that I could recite but struggled to reconcile after having completed my first course in elementary linear algebra.
Earlier this week I looked back in my linear algebra text to see if I could now piece together why this is the case. The following are the results I arrived at. I would greatly welcome any criticism to my thoughts, or further insights into things which I may have overlooked.
The arithmetic argument:
Let $A$ be a $n \times n$ matrix with $n\geq2$. If the columns of $A$ are vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$, then $S$ is the set of these column vectors. $S = v_1,v_2,v_3,...,v_n$. If a vector $v \in S$ is linearly dependent, then it must be that $v = C_1v_1 + C_2v_2+C_3v_3+...C_nv_n$ for $C_i \in \mathbb{R}$. That is to say, $v$ can be expressed as a linear combination of the other vectors is $S$. Now here is where we apply the determinant. Adding any multiple of a column to another column yields no effects on the value of the determinant. Since the linearly dependent column is equal to a linear combination of the other columns, we can subtract these scalar multiples of the other columns to reduce this column to the zero vector. Let the original matrix be $A$ and this column equivalent matrix be $A'$. Note that $A'$ has a column that is the zero vector, thus $det(A') = 0$. Since $A$ and $A'$ are column equivalent and adding scalar multiples of one column to another column does not affect the determinant's value, then $det(A) = det(A') = 0$. Therefore, any square matrix whose columns represent vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ that attains a determinant of zero must contain at least one linearly dependent column (vector).
The geometric argument:
Following the idea that a $n \times n$ matrix $A$ encodes a linear transformation upon the standard basis vectors of $\mathbb{R}^n$, we can see how linear dependence and the determinant interact geometrically. Consider the columns of $A$ to be transformed basis vectors of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then $det(A)$ provides us with a signed value that represents the transformation applied to the $n$ - dimensional unit cube, whose adjacent sides are the basis vectors of $\mathbb{R}^n$. That is, the determinant gives us the signed volume of the $n$ - dimensional parallelotope that the unit cube is transformed into by the linear transformation on the standard basis vectors. If one of these standard basis vectors is linearly dependent with the other, then the dimension of the space which all volumes are mapped to becomes $n-1$, thus, the volume of any $n$-dimensional parallelotope will become zero, because the linear transformation squishes the object into a lower dimension.
In the context of $\mathbb{R}^2$, a linearly dependent column in a transformation matrix indicates that the entire area is now squished onto a single line. The area of line will always be zero, since it has no width.
Similarly, in the context of $\mathbb{R}^3$, a linearly dependent column in the transformation matrix indicates that the volume of the parallelepiped is squished into a two dimensional space. Thus the parallelepiped becomes a parallelogram, which has area, but no height with which to assign it a nonzero volume. Similarly, if the matrix has two linearly dependent columns, the dimension of the parallelepiped will be even further squished onto just a single line.
For $n > 3$, such geometric interpretation make no sense, but we can extrapolate our intuition from $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{R}^3$ to convince ourselves of the validity of this idea in any generalized $n$ dimensional space $\mathbb{R}^n$.
Again, I greatly encourage any criticisms, additions or comments on my thought process.

Is there a particular step you are questioning?  I think you have basically got it

"For $n\geq 3$, such geometric interpretation make no sense" It very much does make sense, it's just a little more difficult to imagine or draw on a piece of paper.

Hi, I can add something here(another way to prove). You may have covered the fact that $det(A) \neq 0 \iff A$ invertible. So immediately, we can say A is non-invertible. That means, when we solve the system of equations $A\mathbf{x}=0$, there will be at least one free variable in the solution , and hence at least one solution with $\mathbf{x}\neq0$. However, $A\mathbf{x}$ is a linear combination of the columns of A. So there is some non-zero relation between the columns of A to sum to zero. So we have proved linear dependence.

@J.D Is this tantamount to saying that for a noninvertible matrix $A$ that $\exists v \in ker(A)$ such that $v \neq 0$?

@MattKuehr Yes , pretty much.
